# Unable to access data from outside the scope of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scope

I have a function that downloads the user input(currently named app.json) from browser(client) to the server

```
  function downloadUpdate(callback) {
  //Using formidable node package for downloading user input to server
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
    file.path = "app.json";
  });

  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({
      fields: fields,
      files: files
    }));
  });

  form.on('end', function() {
    callback(null);
  });
}
```

I have another function that takes the file downloaded above and converts it into required format(final.json) something like this.

```
function UpdateCode(callback) {
    var obj = fs.readFileSync('app.json', 'utf8');
    console.log(abc); //Im getting undefined here
      var object = JSON.parse(obj);
      var data2 = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < object.length; j++) {
        if (object[j].value == `${abc}`) {
          data2.push(object[j]);
        }
      }
      console.log(data2);
      fs.appendFile('final.json', JSON.stringify(data2), function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
        callback(null);
      });
    }
```

I used async series function to make them run in an order like this

```
async.series([
  downloadUpload,
  UpdateCode
], function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

All of this code is inside a post request. I'm getting abc from the server

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){
       var abc = req.body.abc;
       console.log(abc); //I'm getting abc here
     function downloadfile(callback){
//here goes the downloadfile definition
}
function UpdateCode(){
//upload code function
}
//now i call async.series method
 async.series([
      downloadUpload,
      UpdateCode
    ], function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
});
```

the thing is the value of abc is not going to function UploadCode and when I console log abc, I get undefined. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Inside aysnc call you have written "UpdateCode" and function you have defined in you app.post() method is named "UploadCode" . Is it correct ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply..Yeah it's a spelling mistake

Comment: Are `downloadUpdate`, `downloadUpload` and `downloadfile` all the same function? Put `console.log(abc)` directly after the line `var abc = req.body.abc;` to check it is being read in correctly. Then put exactly the same log line at the top of `UpdateCode`, check it hasn't changed at that point.

Comment: Yeah, I did use console.log but it's working properly there. I feel the problem is with the async.series.. I'm confused if I'm using it in the right way

Comment: In the question you say that when you 'console log abc' you get undefined. Where exactly are you doing that logging? Could you add that logging in the code sample you've provided so we can see the exact line that is producing the undefined value?

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check it out

Comment: I'm struggling to see how a variable caught in a closure could change value unless you've got code somewhere that's changing it. I suggest changing the logging slightly so there's less potential for confusion, e.g. `console.log('here1', abc);` and `console.log('here2', abc)`. Perhaps try using `const abc` rather than `var abc` so that any attempt to change its value will throw an error?

Comment: I'm confused as well. I tried for a few hours and changed the entire approach of the app. Thanks for your time